# Wordpress: Hide specific categories from User Role on the Add New page

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, user-roles

Just as title says really;

How can i hide specific categories from specified User Roles in Wordpress on the Add New Post page? So that users of a specific role cannot see the hidden categories (therefore, not post in them either).

I used to do this via a plugin but they havnt been updated in years and i dont seem able to find a replacement. So any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Can you tell what plugin you are already using...and even if hasn't been updated what purpose it isn't solving.

Comment: You're likely going to be able to do something with an action or filter. Have you looked through the source code to find how the list is generated?

Comment: @Plot64 try this one. It should do the work. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8197/how-can-i-hide-a-category-from-contributors-in-the-edit-add-new-post-screen

Answer (score 3):

Answer converted to comment.

Apply this code to your own and should work.

```
add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'yoursite_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2);

function yoursite_list_terms_exclusions( $exclusions, $args ) {

    global $pagenow;
    if (in_array($pagenow,array('post.php','post-new.php')) && !current_user_can('see_special_cats')) {
        $exclusions = " {$exclusions} AND t.slug NOT IN ('slug-one','slug-two')";
    }
    return $exclusions;
}
```

see_special_cats => the level of user in WordPress admin (admin, author etc...)

[More info about users levels in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Comment: Thanks for this - i will give it a shot as well. Any benefit to this method over the plugin i linked to below? ps: where in the cost above do i specify the user roles and/or the categories to be hidden from those user roles?

Comment: @Plot64 which plugin do you mean exactly? As for the second question, could you clarify it a little bit more? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please explain whats happening here ? what categories are being hided for what roles?