# Hide Wordpress Categories from Users by Role

Tags: wordpress, categories

I want to be able to hide certain Wordpress Post Categories from Users dependent on their Role.

I've tried the code here:
[Wordpress: Hide specific categories from User Role on the Add New page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405507/wordpress-hide-specific-categories-from-user-role-on-the-add-new-page)
I think its deprecated, and would really appreciate some help

add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'yoursite_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2);

function yoursite_list_terms_exclusions( $exclusions, $args ) {

```
global $pagenow;
if (in_array($pagenow,array('post.php','post-new.php')) && !current_user_can('see_special_cats')) {
    $exclusions = " {$exclusions} AND t.slug NOT IN ('slug-one','slug-two')";
}
return $exclusions;
```

}

With this code nothing happens. I've tried 10+ different plugins and am really getting desperate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you used any plugin for create user role?

Comment: Used the plugin Members to create user role. Almost have it working with this code - but excludes everything from the role 'cmdr' not 8/9.

!current_user_can is deprecated, had an args whereshould have an exclusion.

add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'yoursite_list_terms_exclusions', 8, 9);

function yoursite_list_terms_exclusions( $exclusions, $args ) {
  global $pagenow;
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( !in_array( 'cmdr', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    //The user has the "cmdr" role
    $args = $exclusions;
  }
  return $args;
}

Comment: can you tell me which plugin you used?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'yoursite_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2);
function yoursite_list_terms_exclusions( $exclusions, $args ) {
  global $pagenow;
  if (in_array($pagenow,array('post.php','post-new.php')) && 
     !current_user_can('see_special_cats')) {
    $exclusions = " {$exclusions} AND t.slug NOT IN ('slug-one','slug-two')";
  }
  return $exclusions;
}
```

This code presumes that you've used a plugin like the [Members plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) to create a [capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) called 'see_special_cats' and that you've assigned it to every role that you want to have access to the categories except of course 'Contributors'.

Since you found the plugin you may not need this, but maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: Paul this is the same code I quoted. it doesn't work as !current_user_can is deprecated. Even without that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'yoursite_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2);

function yoursite_list_terms_exclusions( $exclusions, $args ) {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    // Change 'see_special_cats' to capability user must have to be able see category or categories
    if ( $current_user->has_cap('see_special_cats') ) {
       $capCheck = 1;
    } else {
        $capCheck = 0;
    }
    global $pagenow;
    if (in_array($pagenow,array('post.php','post-new.php')) && !$capCheck) {
        // Change category-slug-one and two to desired categories to hide. Additional categories may be added
        // by separating with a comma. Delete ", 'category-slug-two'" to only hide one category
        $exclusions = " {$exclusions} AND t.slug NOT IN ('category-slug-one', 'category-slug-two')";
    }
    return $exclusions;
}
```

This code works without using current_user_can(). Paste this code in your functions.php file. If you want to hide a category from everyone except for the Administrator role, as set up by the default hierarchical structure, change 'see_special_cats' to 'create_users'. Change category-slug-one and category-slug-two to the category slugs that you want hidden. There is no additional plugin required (I'm not sure where 'see_special_cats' comes from).